# Is there an adjective in English that describes something that didn't exist before but now it does and it makes you happy?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Okay I know it's not going to be easy but I'll do my best to explain what I mean. There's a word in my language which literally translates to English like this: "lack-completing". I know it might sound odd to natives and I'm sure there has to be a word in English that carries the same meaning, I just haven't been able to find it.

I have found *'novel, innovative, revolutionary, unprecedented'* but these are not the ones I'm looking for. Basically this word means that there was a **lack** of something (either of an idea or of an item) until now but finally it has been 'invented' or 'made' and thus it 'fulfills/completes/closes' that lack/void...it makes that 'lack'(of the given thing) cease.

Upon suggestion, here's a list of example sentences where this word would probably fit.

1. This channel on Youtube is simply _______. I'm sure a lot of people felt its absence but it's great to see that somebody is finally creating content about this now.
2. It used to be problematic to handle these situations, but with this new, _______ app people can manage their issues musch faster.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a few sentences which would use this word.   Perhaps:  "When Apple released the ______ Macintosh, it enabled a new generation to be productive using computers."  Is that what you mean?  I think a few examples would help illustrate the concept.

Comment: @guest Welcome to EL&U. Note that comments are sometimes deleted without notice. It’s better to [edit] the examples straight into the text of your question.

Comment: I think __new__ fits your description, but some of your other options, like __novel__, work, too. Is there a reason you are rejecting these?

Comment: Yes they somewhat come close to what i mean, but maybe i 'm just trying to translate literally... which, of course i know many a time doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit mundane, but fits your description:

### gap-filling

> Batman #687 depicts a number of gap-filling moments which longtime readers probably expected to see, but which weren't necessary to the stories other writers wanted to tell.

https://www.cbr.com/shades-of-grayson-rounding-up-junes-bat-books/

Also seems to be used commonly in law [1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/gap_filling) and government, such as:

> the Government's gap-filling regulation

--[Supreme Court's Decision in Home Concrete](https://www.lexisnexis.com/legalnewsroom/tax-law/b/emerging-issues/posts/the-supreme-court-s-decision-in-home-concrete)

and

> gap-filling medical equipment

-- [US government agency document](https://www.cms.gov/Regulations-and-Guidance/Guidance/Transmittals/2018Downloads/R4130CP.pdf)

Comment: I like this answer and upvoted. But, I feel like there must be a less "mundane" answer.  Similarly void-filling, problem-solving, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Ultrasaurus and David M for your help.

Comment: It's also doesn't fulfil the title question's 'and [that] makes you happy' requirement.  For instance, from [ResearchGate.net_Comparison of top-down and bottom-up gap-filling ... picoalga Ostreococcus](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Comparison-of-top-down-and-bottom-up-gap-filling-Fair-comparison-between-top-down-and_fig3_51971235): 'Candidate gap-filling reactions from species closely related to the target species are more likely to feature in the target species’ network. By gap-filling reference networks of decreasing taxonomic diversity, a layered approach to gap-filling was used ....'